# VTC on a question that was reopened

Tags: support, status-bydesign, closing

I just discovered that [How do monster level and act number affect crowd control reduction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80106/how-do-monster-level-and-act-number-affect-crowd-control-reduction) is a duplicate of [How is CC reduced in higher difficulties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69990/how-is-cc-reduced-in-higher-difficulties)

This dup was earlier closed as a duplicate of a very broad question [How do the different difficulty levels affect the gameplay?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/how-do-the-different-difficulty-levels-affect-the-gameplay) and iirc I was one of the close votes (since that was site policy to close narrow questions when subsumed by a broader context). Since then, we've had some discussion and decided against this approach, hence it was reopened later.

However, I am unable to cast a close vote on it - says that I have already voted to close, with 0 close votes shown there. Is this expected behavior or an SE bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is intended behaviour. You can't vote to close twice on a question. This is meant to prevent the same users starting a close/reopen war on the question.